# Core data - DENY rule is not deleting destination objects related to the source object deleted

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two tables. Assignments and Questions. Both the tables has too-many relationships between them. Delete rule from Assignments to Questions is DENY and from Questions to Assignments is Nullify.

When an assignment is deleted, I want to delete all the questions related to that assignment leaving over the questions which still has a reference with other Assignments. This is the reason DENY delete rule is set from Assignment to Questions.

Before deleting Assignment I make sure that I remove the questions reference from assignment as shown in the below:

```
Assignment *assignment = assignment to be deleted;

for (SMQuestion *question in [assignment.questions allObjects])
{
//NSLog(@"The Question ID is %@",question.questionId);

//[question removeAssignmentsObject:assignment];
[assignment removeQuestionsObject:question];
//question.assignments = nil;
}

[[[CoreDataManager sharedObject] managedObjectContext] deleteObject:assignment];

[[[CoreDataManager sharedObject] managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

But after deleting assignment, none of the questions are getting deleted from the database. Is there anything which I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DENY rule does not cause any object to be deleted. It only prevents the source object from being deleted if it has a relationship to the destination object.

In this case (DENY rule from Assignment to Question), an assignment cannot be deleted if it is related to any question.

Your code removes only the relationships from the assignment to the questions. You have to check if the question has any other assigments left, and delete the question otherwise.

Note also that `question.assignments = nil;` in your loop removes *all* assignments from the question, not only the one "assignment to be deleted".

Comment: Thanks Martin. I made the required changes and it is working fine :)